# How to create diagram "Requirements Diagram" with JavaScript in Enterprise Architect

Tags: javascript, scripting, uml, enterprise-architect

Using scripting in Enterprise Architect I can create diagram Use Case of UML:

```
testElement = subPackage.Elements.AddNew( "New diagram", "Use Case" );
testElement.Update();
```

But how to create non-UML diagram? It's about second parameter of AddNew function. In documentation, there is

> This can be either a standard UML metaclass type (such as 'Class' or 'UseCase') or a fully-qualified metatype defined by an MDG Technology (such as 'BPMN2.0::BusinessProcess' or 'SysML1.4::Block').

But what is fully-qualified metatype defined by an MDG Technology? I tried something like "Extended::Requirements Diagram", but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a Diagram in the Elements collection.

The code you posted creates a Use Case , not a diagram.

So the correct code would be

```
newDiagram = subPackage.Diagrams.AddNew( "New diagram", "Extended::Requirements" );
newDiagram.Update();
```

Comment: Thank you! It was in enterprise architect example for diagram creation... Didn't think about that. But it actually created Use Case diagram. Strange... Anyway Diagrams collection is the right way. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Almost. It's `Extended::Requirements`.

Next time create the diagram you want and look into `t_diagram.StyleEx` where you find the stereotype after `MDGDgm=`.

Geert pointed out one issue in your code. If you want to add a diagram to an element you need to do:

```
newDiagram = testElement.Diagrams.AddNew( "New diagram", "Extended::Requirements" );
newDiagram.Update();
```

or use Geert's code for a package.

Comment: Thank you, I see problem with the Elements collection now. I've to use Diagrams.